# How to find $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {n^2}{n^3+n +1} + \frac {n^2}{n^3 +n +2} +.....+\frac {n^2}{n^3 + 2n}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> How to find 
>   $$
> \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac {n^2}{n^3+n +1} + \frac {n^2}{n^3 +n +2} +.....+\frac {n^2}{n^3 + 2n}?
> $$

I was thinking about the Riemann sum, but I am not able to do it.

Comment: Sum of $n$ terms, each between $__$ and $__$ hence the limit is $__$.

Comment: You should take a look here how to ask a good question https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: If the limit of $$\frac{n^3}{n^3+n+1}$$ is not obvious to you, as seems apparent from the comments below, this is the question you should be asking, rather than the one above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{n^{2}}{n^{3}+n+k}\leq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{n^{2}}{n^{3}+n+1}=\dfrac{n^{3}}{n^{3}+n+1}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{n^{2}}{n^{3}+n+k}\geq\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{n^{2}}{n^{3}+n+n}=\dfrac{n^{3}}{n^{3}+2n},
\end{align*}
now use Squeeze Theorem to conclude.

Comment: Thanks @user284331..can u more  elaborate   that  how  can i find $lim x_n$,,as  i search on wolframalpha,,,it show that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\dfrac{n^{2}}{n^{3}+n+k}$ is  diverges ???  Pliz more  elaborate ur answer....

Comment: So by Squeeze Theorem the limit is $1$, I don't understand why Wolfram says that it is divergent.

Comment: W.A. is correct $n \to \infty $ sum is equal to $1$. Series is convergent.  W.A. is correct.

Comment: @user284331 That mean  according to ur answer $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\dfrac{n^{3}}{n^{3}+n+1} =1$,...Is it True/false ? pliz tell me

Comment: Yes, that is true.

Comment: thanks  a lots @user284331